# Qual a utilidade do operador ! no Java?

Tags: java, operadores

Em um `if(!aplicaDescontoDe(valor));`
em que o método `aplicaDescontDe` é um booleano, como funciona não entendi?

Nesse Exemplo:

```
public boolean aplicaDescontoDe(double porcentagem) {
        if(porcentagem >0.3) { //se desconto for maior que 30%
            return false;
        }
        this.valor -= this.valor * porcentagem;
        return true;
    }
```

...

```
if(!livro.aplicaDescontoDe(0.3)) {
          System.out.println("Desconto no livro nao pode ser maior que 30%");
      } else {
          System.out.println("Valor no livro com desconto: " + livro.getValor());
      }
```

Por que preciso do `!`(exclamação) no `if` ?

Comment: O operador `!` funciona como uma negação, ou seja, se retornar 1, a função sera negada e passara como 0, se retornar 0 sera negada e passara como 1.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio, não é possível utilizar o operador `!` (_not_) em  valores inteiros, quando você diz `1` e `0` você quer dizer `true` (`1`) e `false` (`0`)?

Comment: @Fernando foi um infeliz exemplo rs, o que quis dizer foi: `if(!funcao())` se o retorno da função for 1 ou `true`, ele será negado, e vice versa, se o retorno por acaso for um `int,` ai dá uma `exception`(acredito)

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio, desconfiei, só citei pois novatos podem ver isso e ficarem confusos, e no caso de tentar fazer uma negação em um inteiro: `if(!1)`, por exemplo, gerará um erro de compilação e não de execução, como pode ser visto [aqui](http://ideone.com/AJu5FL).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ele é o operador lógico de negação (conhecido como `not`) e ele só se aplica mesmo à dados booleanos. Ou seja, se ele receber um `true` ele transforma em `false` e vice-versa. Então:

```
bool x = !true;
```

é o mesmo que

```
bool x = false;
```

Obviamente só coloquei assim para ilustrar, não faz sentido usá-lo com o literal, só em variáveis ou expressões que resultem em booleano, como você usou.

Ele pode ser usado em qualquer lugar que aceite uma expressão e operando unário seja um booleano e o resultado também deva ser um booleano. Não precisa ser só em um `if`.

O seu exemplo `if(!aplicaDescontoDe(valor))` pode ser lido assim: "se não aplica desconto de valor".

No exemplo postado posteriormente seria possível fazer sem o operador, bastaria inverter os blocos, assim:

```
if(livro.aplicaDescontoDe(0.3)) {
    System.out.println("Valor no livro com desconto: " + livro.getValor());
} else {
    System.out.println("Desconto no livro nao pode ser maior que 30%");
}
```

O resultado seria o mesmo. Como curiosidade, é gosto, mas eu faria diferente:

```
System.out.println(livro.aplicaDescontoDe(0.3) ? 
          "Valor no livro com desconto: " + livro.getValor() :
          "Desconto no livro nao pode ser maior que 30%");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/NotOperator.java).

[Artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective).

Comment: agora já sou java sênior.

Comment: Eeeeee não! kkk

Comment: Tudo !mentira o que ele falou.